# Could not login

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

I can not login with my Stack Exchange account it keep saying no account found.

> Is this just my account?

Yeah I double check the email address and password.

So as it turns out that I can login via other oAuth provider Stack Exchange. I think this is a bug.

Comment: What do you use as the username?!

Comment: as on normal, my email address which I use for Stack Exchange oAuth

Comment: Did it work before?

Comment: No, I'm in beta since today

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, click the button that says `Log in using another OpenId`, then click login with StackExchange, login, and you should be good to go. This happend to me, too, and that let me login.

Comment: That's right, thank you sir I will accept your answer when I can

Comment: @Sirl33tname This may be a bug or something, not sure why it's like this.

Comment: possible or it's because the beta thanks anyway and I tag this as bug

Answer (score 3):

This was a server side issue that has been fixed as of the last build-out, thanks for reporting it.

Comment: I try it and it work for me, well done!